# fopen: failed to open stream: Permission denied on directory with 755

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, permissions

I am getting the error

```
fopen(/var/www/photos/testphoto.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

when PHP is attempting to write a file to `/var/www/photos`, whose directory permissions are

```
drwxrwsr-x 3 root www-pub 4096 Oct 11 01:46 photos
```

I have already added apache2 user `www-data` to the group `www-pub`, why is it still unable to write files to the directory unless I `chmod 777 /var/www/photos`?

---

### Update

As suggested by Laurentiu Roescu, I did a `chmod 777 photos` and let PHP write the file. Here's the output of `ls -la`

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-pub 34777 Oct 11 02:12 testphoto.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a chmod 777 on folder and create a file. Then please give the output of ls -la on that file.

Comment: Updated in original post

Comment: Seems ok. Have you restarted apache after setting permissions to that folder? And you should also check selinux.

Comment: Somehow it works now, I guess I restarted Apache! :)